# Version check in ionic - how to get existing installed apps to update?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, version

Folks,

Simple question. I have an ionic cordova app on the app store (ios and Android). A few hundred downloads have already happened. The version of the app that is out there has no version checking feature.

I have created a new release of the app (releasing next week). When installed, this release will have code (in app.component.ts) to check whether the current version of the app is the latest version (I have a Rest Api that tells me what the correct latest version is and this is compared to whatever version is currently running on the user's device ).

That works like charm. I've tested it. But how will existing, alreadt installed app (which does not have the version check code in app.component.ts), ever get updated. Unless the user decides to update it manually.

Any and all suggestions appreciated.

Thanks!!
JR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interim, here is what I intend to do.

On the first REST API called from the root page of my app, I will change the structure of the endpoint. If the original structure is called, it will only return a message prompting the user to update the app. The user can chose to ignore the message, but will not be able to enjoy the app.

I know this will work, and happy to post the code for you all, but wondering if there is another way to do this.

Regards,
JR